# Why is Hibernate not filling this foreign key column

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm

This problem seems occur often, but I couldn't find a working solution for my case. Problem is that Hibernate leaves the foreign key of one foreign key column empty (null). Strange thing is that I use the same setup of these two affected tables in another program and it works fine. Only difference is that I now added 2 other tables.

I checked the MySQL output (via show_sql option) and Hibernate inserts the parent table before the child. So the key should be there.

Parent:

```
public class Page {

@Id  
@GeneratedValue  
@Column(name="page_id")
private Integer id; 

//****** THIS IS THE CHILD
@OneToMany(orphanRemoval=true, mappedBy="pageId", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Tag> tag = new HashSet<Tag>();


//****** THESE ARE THE NEW TABLES
@OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private Video video;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="creator_id")
private Creator creator;
```

Child:

```
public class Tag {

@Id  
@GeneratedValue  
private Integer id; 

@Index(name = "tag")
@Column
private String tag;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name="page_id")
private Page pageId;
```

How it is saved (saveOrUpdate is necessary):

```
public static void save(SessionFactory sessionFactory, Page page) {
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();     
    session.saveOrUpdate(page);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

Every suggestion are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you managing both sides of the association?  Meaning that you add the `Tag` to the `Set<Tag>` in `Page` and set the `Page` field on the `Tag`?

Before passing `Page` to the `save` method you should be managing the relationship as follows:

```
Page page = new Page();
Tag tag = new Tag();

//managing the both sides of the relationship
tag.setPage(page); //Setting Tags page field
page.getTags().add(tag); //Adding tag to the `Set<Tag>`
```

Comment: @Glad I could help! I struggled with this too at first.